Error 2019: Member Mapping Not Valid for NUMBER(2,0) to Int16 in Oracle Managed Data Access with EF6
I am working with a .NET Framework 4.8 project using Oracle 19c and the latest Oracle.ManagedDataAccess (23.6.1) and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework (23.4.0) and Entity Framework (6.5.1) packages. I have an EDMX model where a column SECTION_NO in the ACADEMIC_ADVISING table is defined as NUMBER(2,0) in Oracle.
By default, this column was being mapped to byte, but I updated my App.config to map it as Int16. Here is my updated configuration:
`<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <version number="*">
    <edmMappings>
      <edmNumberMapping>
        <add NETType="int16" MinPrecision="2" MaxPrecision="2" DBType="Number" />
      </edmMappings>
    </edmMappings>
  </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>`

After regenerating the EDMX model, SECTION_NO is mapped to Int16 as expected. However, whenever I open the project in Visual Studio or rebuild it, I get the following error:
Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Int16[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=]' of member 'SECTION_NO' in type 'Model.ACADEMIC_ADVISING' is not compatible with 'OracleEFProvider.number[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=2,Scale=0]' of member 'SECTION_NO' in type 'Model.Store.ACADEMIC_ADVISING'.
Here is what I have tried so far:
1- Verified the database column definition:
COLUMN_NAME: SECTION_NO
DATA_TYPE: NUMBER
DATA_PRECISION: 2
DATA_SCALE: 0
2- Updated the App.config file as shown above to include explicit edmNumberMapping.
3- Rebuilt the EDMX file and ensured that the SECTION_NO property is mapped as Int16.
Despite these steps, the error persists whenever I close and reopen the project in Visual Studio. The error temporarily disappears after rebuilding the project.
How can I resolve this issue permanently so the mapping between NUMBER(2,0) and Int16 is consistently recognized by Oracle Managed Data Access and Entity Framework? Are there additional configurations required for Oracle EF or Visual Studio?
